# Save binned data from numpy.histogram2d to text file

Tags: python, numpy, histogram2d

I want to do a 2d histogram using python and save the result as a three columns data file(x, y, histogram). The 2d data just looks like this:

```
  x        y
-0.609  -3.042
-0.528  -2.861
-1.219  -2.938
-0.196  -2.007
0.173   -3.128
1.600   -3.885
2.112   -2.432 
...
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Can you show your attempts, SO is not a code writing service

Comment: What will the x and y columns represent in your output?  Bin centroids?  Bin boundaries?

Comment: Thank you for reminding. I want to do a density map with the points. So I have to do histogram first. X and Y are bin centroids!